# Validation just for new records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have a model `Order` with the `price` attribute.

There are few `Order` records in the database without a `price` attribute(`nil` value) which was imported from the old database. There are less than 20 *invalid* records like this.

Now the `price` attribute is mandatory.

I need to add a presence validation of the `price` **and** preserve the old records.
I can't set the `nil` values to zero or some random values.

I have some crazy ideas about the conditional validation on the basis of the timestamp or even a list of "permitted" ids.

Something like this:

```
PERMITTED_IDS = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42]
validates :price, presence: true, if: -> { |order| PERMITTED_IDS.exclude?(order.id) }
```

Is there any **nice** and **convenient** way for that?

Comment: Your solution is probably the way to go!

Comment: Are old/imported records editable?

Comment: I would suggest to also create a `Set` out of `PERMITTED_IDS` for O(1) lookup

Comment: @Stefan yes, but I can't set the `price` to zero for them.

Answer (score 4):

### Use `on: :create`

The following will only validate when the model is created.

```
validates :price, presence: true, on: :create
```

However, can't you just use `allow_nil: true`:

```
validates :price, presence: true, allow_nil: true
```

Comment: `allow_nil` is ignored by `presence` validator, 
 I need the validation for all the normal actions (save, initialize) as well

Answer (score 1):

I would add a boolean `imported` attribute to the `Order` class, setting it to `true` for old records upon import. This allows you to skip validations for these records easily:

```
validates :price, presence: true, unless: :imported?
```

**UPDATE**

> **Stefan:** Are old/imported records editable?
>
> **freemanoid:** @Stefan yes, but I can't set the price to zero for them.

The above solution is not an option because it would allow a `nil` price for all old records.

You could use a custom validation that requires a price for new records, but allows `nil` when updating records if the price was already `nil`. Something like:

```
validates :price, presence: true,
                  on: :create

validates :price, presence: true,
                  on: :update,
                  unless: Proc.new { |o| p.price_was.nil? }
```

Comment: I have several thousands of objects and only ~10-20 of them are `imported`.

Comment: @freemanoid several thousand bytes are not that much (a boolean requires 1 byte)

Comment: Agreed, but an additional field in the database is a bit confusing for new developers.